# Not powering down after installing upstart

Tags: power

I just installed upstart from the repositories, and I am now facing a strange behaviour:
To properly shutdown (power down), I need to run `shutdown -r` then `shutdown -h`. To reboot it is the opposite (-h then -r). `poweroff` and `reboot` commands do work, but without exiting all running process.

When I run not both but just one of these commands, it seems that a first event is triggered, that exits my network interfaces, but I get back to the command line and the shutdown process does not continue. I also get the message

```
stty: standard input: unable to perform all requested operations
```

My first question is then: how do I find logs to troubleshoot this issue.

This was just caused by one of my upstart shutdown script not properly working

Thanks

Comment: This question is unrelated to the Raspberry Pi. It would probably be better received on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just caused by one of my upstart shutdown script not properly working

Comment: Since the question and answer have limited use for others, at least as is. You may want to consider deleting the question.